# Domain Controller takes forever to boot up after running dnscmd /Config /SocketPoolSize

Tags: dns, exchange-server-2010

Ever since I ran the command `dnscmd /Config /SocketPoolSize 9100` my Win'2008R2 dc is not working properly and is stuck for hrs at Applying Computer Settings after rebooting before it finally logs in. Obviously 9100 was a big mistake but I figured by re-running the same command but specifying 2500 (default) that things would be fine. I was wrong.

So I've deleted the SocketPoolSize afterwards directly from the registry in `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\DNS\Parameters` in hopes of undoing it but the system still takes hrs before I can finally login. I have a feeling that the dnscmd command I ran and reverted is just coincidence and perhaps something else is causing Exchange service to get stuck with "Starting"

This is also preventing some services from starting (ie: Exchange 2010 - not best practice on DC, I know but it was never a problem).

Is there anything else that happens after running that command? Is there a way I can undo it using the same command or some other (rather than thru the registry)?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it had nothing to do with the dnscmd command I ran. I forgot that days ago I temporarily disabled Tcpipv6 on the network adapter but never rebooted until today after running the dnscmd. This incorrectly lead me to believe it was something to do with dnscmd.